# LXC: Forward container's localhost traffic to host's localhost

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding, containers

I have service A running on the host and binding to port 127.0.0.1:7800.

I have service B running inside my LXC container which want to connect to service A via 127.0.0.1:7800 but currently can't.

How do I setup the container or iptables to forward the traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the container side you should add these rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT \
         -d 127.0.0.1 \
         -p tcp --dport 7800 \
    -j DNAT --to-address <HOST.EXT.IP>

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING \
         -o <LXC.HOST.IFACE> \
         -d <HOST.EXT.IP> -s 127.0.0.1 \
         -p tcp --dport 7800 \
    -j MASQUERADE
```

Also it requires enabling of `net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet` sysctl option.

Because on the host app listens only `127.0.0.1` address, that means it cannot accept the external connections by default. But you can use the `DNAT/REDIRECT` targets as workaround.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING \
         -i <HOST.LXC.IFACE> \
         -d <HOST.LXC.IP> -s <LXC.IP> \
         -p tcp --dport 7800 \
    -j DNAT --to-address 127.0.0.1:7800
```

It also requires enabled `route_localnet` option.

Use the `iptables-save -c` (check the rule counters) and `tcpdump` to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks, this improves my understanding. With `tcpdump` I see the following: `IP localhost.57690 > hostHostname.7800` . This means the host will have trouble to respond since the source IP is seen as localhost?

Comment: Yep. You should add `MASQUERADE` rule